# How to Transform ISO 8601 Duration in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm getting an ISO 8601 Duration variable from my API call.

An example data point is this: `"P15DT16H17M37S"`

This is my backend call which returns the JSON

```
 const cardsData = newData.map(card => ({
        timeLeft: moment.duration(card.TimeLeft)
      }));

      let cards = JSON.stringify(cardsData);

      res.send(cards);
```

On my front end in react, if i don't transform the data it does come back like this `P15DT16H17M37S`

And here's the mapping and transforming on front end i'm trying to do with moment

if i don't include toString() it creates some weird endless loop, but with toString() the page renders correctly yet with the same ISO string `P15DT16H17M37S`

```
filteredData.map(card => 

  <Table.Cell textAlign="center">
                    {moment.duration(card.timeLeft).toString()}
                  </Table.Cell>
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/ ?

Comment: as my code displays, that is exactly what I'm trying to do but it's not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It works as expected, and you haven't explained what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: It means that it isn’t transforming the ISO string.  I just want to return a readable duration, like 5 Hours, 20 Minutes.  Maybe I’m misunderstanding how to use moment  with duration but I thought it automatically did this.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/ ?

Comment: ok yep that's it, sorry for confusion...can't believe i forgot this